# archive by category not showing when using query_post()

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress theme I need to hide all posts from a category, Si I am using this code

```
<?php query_posts('cat=-307'); ?> 
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
...
```

It works great, but then when I try to view all posts that a specific category, e.g. category/jquery I dont get only the jquery posts, but I get all the posts again.

If I remove the fist line of the code above, then it works as expected.

I have used the boilerplate theme, so the rest of the code is not the problem.

How can I fix this by keeping the `query_posts()` filter but also get only specific categories when needed

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I just beed the query_posts() to take effect on the homepage of the blog. So all I did was, removed

```
<?php query_posts('cat=-307'); ?>
```

from the `loop.php` and added it to `index.php`